# $this->db->affected_rows() returns -1 after query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a query like this in codeigniter

```
$update= $this->db->query("update aas set aa = 'aa'  where no=" . $this->db->escape($No) . "");
```

When I run

```
echo  $this->db->affected_rows()  or echo $this->db->affected_rows($update)
```

it returns -1

When updating any row which exists I get -1
Even when I have no row to update it still shows -1.

What is the issue?  I am using codeigniter 2.1.0 with mysqli drivers

I have tried running it in phpmyadmin and it gives me the proper 0 or 1 rows affected as per the data.But when i run it through codeigniter I get -1 even when The value to be updated has changed or remained same

The query is true always in codeigniter

Is it because I have turned on codeigniter mysqli drivers

Comment: Can you try running the query as you have it, directly on the database? Just make sure that the intended query actually runs directly, and then if it does, we can keep debugging :)

Comment: I have tried running it in phpmyadmin and it gives me the proper 0 or 1 rows affected as per the data.But when i run it through codeigniter I get -1

Answer (score 4):

> Displays the number of affected rows, when doing "write" type queries
>   (insert, update, etc.).

Reference: [**Here**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html).

Incorrect (quotes) in your `sql` statement (so not being executed)

```
$update= $this->db->query("update aas set aa = 'aa'  where no=" . $this->db->escape($No) . "");
```

should be

```
$update = $this->db->query("update aas set aa = 'aa'  where no = '{$this->db->escape($No) }'"); 
echo  $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Comment: The query is true always in codeigniter.    I have tried running it in phpmyadmin and it gives me the proper 0 or 1 rows affected as per the data.But when i run it through codeigniter I get -1 even when The value to be updated has changed or remained same




Is it because I have turned on codeigniter mysqli drivers

Answer (score 0):

It's totally up to you, but you could also convert this query into CodeIgniter's [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update). Not only does it escape everything for you automatically, its easier to use for simple queries and avoid a potential issue with incorrect quotes in your SQL statements.

So, for Active Record, it would look like this:

```
$data = array(
    'aa' => 'aa'
);

$this->db->where('no', $No)->update('aas', $data);

echo $this->db->affected_rows(); // this should return 1 now
```

Comment: I have tried running it in phpmyadmin and it gives me the proper 0 or 1 rows affected as per the data.But when i run it through codeigniter I get -1 even when The value to be updated has changed or remained same

The query is true always in codeigniter so there is no need for active records right now